# CKEditor - Image Too Wide for Editor Box

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I've managed to configure CKEditor and CKFinder to work together in an in-house CMS and I'm coming to the closing stages.

One UI issue I'm having, however, concerns images in the editor WYSIWYG box.

My editor box is roughly 1000px wide, but some images are 1400px wide. They are obviously too big for the editor box and bring in a horizontal scrollbar.

I don't want to set a width on the actual image as this will change the final HTML code, so what are my options for reducing the size of the image ONLY when it's displayed in the CKEditor window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS for this. CKEditor uses class `cke_editable` for the contents, so put the following line in `config.js` as the last line, after the definition of `CKEDITOR.editorConfig`

```
CKEDITOR.addCss('.cke_editable img { max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }');
```